# MongoDbBundle how to access manager in an arbitray class

Tags: mongodb, symfony, bundle

in Symfony2 samples I can find how to access mongodb in from the Controller class:

```
$dm=$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
```

how to do it in an arbitray class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) to inject the `doctrine_mongodb` **service** into your class like this.

Create your class like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class MyClass 
{
    protected $documentManager;

    // ObjectManager is the interface used only for type-hinting here
    // DocumentManager or EntityManager are the actual implementations
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        // The property $documentManager is now set to the DocumentManager
        $this->documentManager=$om;
    }

    public function findSomething()
    {
        // now do something with the DocumentManager
        return $this->documentManager->getRepository('YourBundle:SomeDocument')->findBy(array(/* ... */));
        // ...
    }
```

Then declare this class as a service:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    your_service_name:
        class:     Namespace\Your\SomeClass
        arguments: ['@doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager']
```

In order to access your class from a controller it's service name to get it from the container (the DocumentManager will then be injected automatically into the constructor)

```
// Vendor/YourBundle/Controller/SomeController.php

public function doWhatever()
{
    $myClassService = $this->get('your_service_name');
    $something = $myClassService->findSomething();
}
```